# wp: make the <section> clickable for certain post types

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

The structure of the index/archive page looks like this

```
<article <?php post_class(); ?> > 
    <header>
        <h1><a href=""></a></h1>
    </header>
    <section>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </section>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</article>
```

I want to make the "section" clickable. I think it can be done with javascript/jquery but i would prefer with css.

What do you think? What would be the best solution for this?

I've tried this http://www.avtex.com/blog/2012/01/27/how-to-make-an-entire-div-clickable-with-css/ and it doesn't work somehow it messes up everything.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you want to do when clicked? The only way you can do this in CSS is by wrapping the section tag in an anchor with href!

Comment: when clicked on section -> post page. your solution doesn't work on ie7 or ie8

Comment: Try some CSS for the `a` tag `{display: block;}`

Comment: it doesnt work, i found a solution, but it has some errors, look below.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `section` to be clickable you can set this rule:

```
section { cursor:pointer }
```

and assign a function to be called on click:

```
$('section').on('click', function() {
   // your function
});
```

**UPDATE (Alternative)**

If you don't want to use jQuery, you can just wrap the whole section in to an anchor like the following demo:

```css
section {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #d8d8d8;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <section>
    Section contents
  <section>
</section>
```

Comment: This answers the question. However it is not clear from the question the intent.

Comment: the alternative to wrap the whole thing in a link is not working in ie7 or ie8.

Comment: look at my answer below, it works but it has a glitch i dont know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your section tag with an `a` tag ([HTML5 compliant](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element)). It would look like this:

```
<a href="http://google.com">
  <section>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
  </section>
</a>
```

Comment: it doesn't work if there is an image in the post. i just tried it.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on with your posts but this does work entirely. Here is a demo, http://jsfiddle.net/rLe4L7u3/ -- You should use your console's developer tools to inspect what's going on in your post content.

Comment: Works only for IE9+ unfortunately i need this to work also for ie8 and ie7.

Comment: You'll need to use JavaScript to accomplish this then.

Comment: Try setting `display: block` to your `A` in CSS

Answer (score 0):

Another non-recommended way is

```
<article  <?php post_class(); ?>> 
    <header><h1><a href=""></a></h1>
    <a href="#">
        <section>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </section>
    </a>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</article>
```

It works for me sometimes.

Although, the answer you link in your question will should work too.

I hope it helps

Comment: it has the same result as kel answer. it doesnt work if it's an image in the post.

Comment: Yes, he is faster than me! Anyway, why don't work the post that you link in your question?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but i still need help. 
`<section onclick="document.location='<?php the_permalink() ?>'" >` Works even in IE7.

But if I have links or images in the post somehow they are clickable and they shouldn't be.
I've tried putting the the z-index for section to z-index:99999999999999.

Any ideas? Thanks.